# magento 2 model update recommendation

Tags: magento2

I'm writing a Magento 2 module that after successfully placing an order the order is stored in our backend system as well. The module sends the Magento order via a REST API. The API returns back our backend order id (e.g. `external_order_id`).

I need to store `external_order_id` in magento. My question is what is considered the "correct" approach in Magento 2?

1. Create a new custom flat table that would hold `external_order_id` (I would also store Magento's order Id)
2. I see a field in `sales_order` called `extOrderId` and wondering if better to us this field to store `external_order_id`
3. neither 1 or 2 and use?

If recommended to use #2, what method do I call to update `extOrderId`?

Answer (score 0):

As in M1 the right place to link such data is in the order table, "sales_order" you should create a sales_order attribute instead to modify the database directly (maintaining abstraction) you can achieve this using the method:

```
// Magento/Sales/Setup/SalesSetup.php
SalesSetup::addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
```

That is very similar to M1, you can instantiate this model in your install setup or extend it.

Just take a look in

> [magento_root]/vendor/magento/module-sales/Setup

folder and you'll find a good approach of how to do it in M2.